# Swift iOS : Programmatically create a responsive menu using UIButton and a View and constraints

Tags: ios, swift, responsive-design

In the `viewDidLoad()` method I would like to create 10 UIButtons, title them
`["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]`
and add them to a View in a way that they are always responsively placed using constraints.

I would like to the `UIButton` to a `View` which is always on the top of the page but is responsive to User positioning of the device and the text that is placed into the `UIButton.title`.

This is the same thing that Bootstrap CSS does using the CSS classes "table", "row", "col-md-2".

Example of layout:
[image]

If the titles of the buttons change, the code should auto-magically adjust the positioning as such:

[image]

Comment: [**TagListView**](https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView)

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for a `StackView`.  Have you used them before?

Comment: What is the issue that your having?

Comment: I would use a collectionview

Answer (score 0):

Use `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, make your controller conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol and then for each cell just calculate the width of the `UIButton` and then provide the size to the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Something like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemWidth = ...//calculate the width of the button
    return CGSize(width: kCGImagePropertyIPTCExtMaxAvailWidth, height: 50)//set height to whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the commenter said..... use a Stack View, a collection view is overkill.